# Showing that $\{f_n \}$ converges to $f$ is equivalent to $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_X \frac{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}{1+|f_n(x)-f(x)|}d\mu(x)=0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. We say that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ in measure if, for any $\epsilon>0$
>   $$ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mu\Big(\{x\in X: |f_n(x)-f(x)| \ge \epsilon  \}\Big)=0.$$
>
> 1. Show that $\{f_n \}$ converges to $f$ in measure if $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int_X \frac{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}{1+|f_n(x)-f(x)|}d\mu(x)=0.$$
> 2. Suppose $\mu(X) < \infty$. Show that 
>      $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int_X \frac{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}{1+|f_n(x)-f(x)|}d\mu(x)=0$$
>      if $\{ f_n \}$ converges to $f$ in measure.

Comment: What have you tried? (You might want to answer the several similar requests made on your previous questions--or people here could decide you are simply *using* them.)

Comment: Copy/pasting a question (hint included) straight from a textbook is *not* the best way to get a good answer. Tell us about what you have tried, or at least what kinds of tools you have available.

Comment: So, instead of providing some show of effort, you choose to point out that the question is from an old exam instead of from a textbook. Do you really think that makes the question better posed?

Comment: It is not the source of the question that is questioned, but the lack of background: what is causing you trouble; what have you tried. It is easier to provide help if these are known.

Answer (score 3):

You have to assume $\mu(X)<\infty$. Without loss of generality, let $f_n\to 0$ in measure. Then for any $\varepsilon>0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\{x\in X: |f_n(x)|\ge \varepsilon\})=0$. Note that the function $\frac{t}{1+t}$ is increasing for $t>-1$. So
$$\int_X\frac{|f_n(x)|}{1+|f_n(x)|}d\mu(x)=\int_{|f_n|\ge\varepsilon}\frac{|f_n(x)|}{1+|f_n(x)|}d\mu(x)+\int_{|f_n|\le\varepsilon}\frac{|f_n(x)|}{1+|f_n(x)|}d\mu(x)\le\int_{|f_n|\ge\varepsilon}1d\mu(x)+\int_{|f_n|\le\varepsilon}\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}d\mu(x)\le \mu({|f_n|\ge\varepsilon})+\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}\mu(X).$$
Thus for $\forall \varepsilon>0$,
$$ \overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}\int_X\frac{|f_n(x)|}{1+|f_n(x)|}d\mu(x)\le \frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}\mu(X)$$
and hence
$$ \overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}\int_X\frac{|f_n(x)|}{1+|f_n(x)|}d\mu(x)=0.$$
Conversely, note, for $\forall\varepsilon>0$, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_X\frac{|f_n(x)|}{1+|f_n(x)|}d\mu(x)&=&\int_{|f_n|\ge\varepsilon}\frac{|f_n(x)|}{1+|f_n(x)|}d\mu(x)+\int_{|f_n|\le\varepsilon}\frac{|f_n(x)|}{1+|f_n(x)|}d\mu(x)\\
&\ge&\int_{|f_n|\ge\varepsilon}\frac{|f_n(x)|}{1+|f_n(x)|}d\mu(x)\\
&\ge&\int_{|f_n|\ge\varepsilon}\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}d\mu(x)\\
&=&\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}\mu(|f_n|\ge\varepsilon).
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X\frac{|f_n(x)|}{1+|f_n(x)|}d\mu(x)=0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(|f_n|\ge\varepsilon)=0$ or $f_n\to 0$ in measure.

Comment: You have to assume $\mu(X<\infty)$, Right. You finished the second part. How about the first part?

Comment: @GenmingWang: well, maybe it is *your* turn to do some thinking.

Comment: @GenmingWang: Now it is complete.